# What is the equivalent of Application.ExecutablePath in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

In a windows forms application, I use Application.Executable path to get to the App.config.,

I need to get to app.config  in Windows Service.. What would that be ?

Comment: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

For the current assembly. or, you can derive it from a type:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyAssemblyType)).Location
```

Then (on either) you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the folder it's originating from (assuming your app.config is within that same directory).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [AppDomain.BaseDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

> Gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for
>   assemblies.

The most common usage would be similar to

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConfigurationManager` to read App.config :

1. Add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project.
2. Use `ConfigurationManager` like this to read App.config :

   ```
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeySample"]
   ```

   In the config file you can add your keys like this :

   ```
   <configuration>
       <appSettings>
          <add key="KeySample" value="SampleValue"/>
       </appSettings>
   </configuration>
   ```

   So you don't have to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

Possible options are:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

OR

```
Assembly.Location
```

OR

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

Personally, I used the last one.